# Testing a quiz application that requires audio responses

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, automated-tests

I have a quiz application, which has audio questions and answers. I am using howler.js to play the audio questions, and using MediaStreamRecorder.js to record the audio responses. These are uploaded to s3, and later evaluated by the teacher, and scores are provided later.

I want to build an automation test suite for this application. I want my application to wait till the audio is played, and then answer the question through (probably mock using existing audio responses). What is the best framework to achieve this? I wrote some part of code using Ruby selenium webdriver as the application is built using Rails.

I couldn't find a proper way to achieve the mocking of audio responses and media recording.

Comment: Why are you using mocks if it's a full UI test? if you're trying to do tests with audio can you dive down one layer (API/Web Service/Stream/...)?

Comment: @lloyd can you suggest me a better approach to validate this, the UI goes to next screen only if audio recording is complete else validation fails

Comment: Have a look at [how to test a chatbot](https://chatbotsmagazine.com/how-to-test-a-chatbot-part-1-why-is-it-so-hard-10f1ee8ca37d). MediaStreamRecorder and howler have tests on [github](https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder) [howler github](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js). you could use a question and answer that is predictable.